# Flutter using wrap_content for TabBarView

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

in this below code i have `Wrap` widget into `TabBarView` and i'm not sure as this widget size, when i use `Container` with specify `height` my problem solved, but i miss some layouts which i want to show that with `map`, how can i resolve this problem? i tested `SizedBox.expand` but it doesn't any change

```
Flexible(
  child: TabBarView(
    children: [
      Center(
        child: Wrap(
          children: feeds.map((feed){
            return Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width /3.5,
              height:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width /3.5,
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
              child: GridTile(
                header: feed.feedType ==1?Icon(Icons.video_call)
                child: Center(
                    child: ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3.0)
                        child: Image.asset(feed.feedImage))),
              ),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    ],
    controller: tabController,
  ),
),
```

Comment: I'm having this same issue. There's some conversation here about `Container`s wrapping content. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/4949